# Error Pop up in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to show a pop up to a user when he want to submit a text on a textbox and click on a button to submit it. If for example he want to save a wrong text or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or just try a [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Which would be better than using a third-party library if no special functionality is needed. Some usage samples: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/delivering-message-using?mz=27249-windowsphone7

Answer (score 0):

If you need a custom control, you could also use the silverlight 3 child window control with the windows phone 7.  It animates nicely, and since it is part of the silverlight dlls it is not third party.

[Using child window in windows phone 7](http://wildermuth.com/2010/08/17/Using_ChildWindow_in_Windows_Phone_7_Projects)